# Proper way to handle Cursor objects

Tags: android, cursor

When you call .close() on a Cursor Object, does it mean that for the rest of the Activity's duration it cannot be used? The following is a method within my Manager Object:

```
Cursor cursor = null;

try {
    SQLiteDatabase db = openDb();
    cursor = db.query("table", null, "id=?", new String[] { id }, null, null, null);

    cursor.moveToFirst();
    long dateTime = cursor.getLong(1);

    cursor.close();
    return dateTime ;
} catch (CursorIndexOutOfBoundsException e) {
    return -1;
} finally {
    if (cursor != null) {
        cursor.close();
    }
    closeDb();
}
```

This is the method that's throwing me an IllegalStateException. However, there's a slight twist: it only throws an error the second time it is called. Tracing the stacktrace, I find that the line causing me trouble is the following:

```
Cursor cursor = db.query("table", null, "id=?", new String[] { id }, null, null, null);
```

Just to clear things up a bit, this method can be called several times within the Activity's lifetime through clicking of a particular ListView item. The openDb() and closeDb() methods are as follows:

```
public SQLiteDatabase openDb() {
    if (mDbHelper == null) {
        mDbHelper = new DatabaseHelper(mContext);
    }
    return mDbHelper.getWritableDatabase();
}

public void closeDb() {
    mDbHelper.close();
}
```

And these are stored in the superclass of my Manager object. mDbHelper is a static Object.

Being fairly new to Android programming, I'm wondering why this would throw me an exception. The only logical explanation I can think of is that Cursor Objects are actually re-used, and they should not be closed for the duration of an activity. Am I right? And if I am, when do you actually close the Cursor?

**---EDIT---**

Having tinkered around with the code a bit, I seem to be getting the exception being thrown on a much more irregular basis. For some odd reason, it seems to happen randomly; I can click on eight multiple ListView items with no issues, and suddenly bam! The ninth causes the application to crash.

Because clicking on a ListView also invokes a method which updates that very same table (which up till now has caused me no problems thus far), I think it's only relevant that I include that as well:

```
try {
    SQLiteDatabase db = openDb();

    ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
    cv.put("id", id);
    cv.put("dateTime", dateTime);
    long affected = db.replace("table", null, cv);

    return affected;
} finally {
    closeDb();
}
```

As you can see, no rocket science is involved here. However, this method has now started to throw similar Exceptions, happening on the line:

```
long affected = db.replace("table", null, cv);
```

I'm starting to suspect that it's a click-too-fast problem, and the SQLite connections are not given enough time to close. Because there is no pattern to the crashes that I can discern; sometimes it crashes on the third try, sometimes on the eighth, sometimes it even seems to work fine till well past the tenth.

Could that be possible?

Comment: Thanks for the answers and comments guys, but since there doesn't seem to be an answer to the randomness, I developed a workaround to catch all the Exceptions and do stuff when they happen. I'm sure there's an answer somewhere out there that will solve the problem completely, and mind is only a temporary method, so I'm going to leave this question open for people to answer first.

Answer (score 1):

As the [docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/Cursor.html#close%28%29) say after you have called `close()` your Cursor becomes forever invalid.

Also, there's no need to call close 2 times in your function. It's enough to call it in the `finally` block only

Comment: I create a new Cursor using db.query() every time though. So that shouldn't be a problem should it?

Comment: @Wakka02 there is no problem in that as long as you remember to close it after its use.

Comment: I do close it though. I've included cursor.close() in all my finally statements. Thanks to Alex for pointing out the double .close() here though, I've fixed that already. Still, no avail. :/

Answer (score 0):

Because you call the close() method on the static object, it may not necessarily "nullify" the static object. So when you check if mDbHelper is null in the openDb() method the second time, it will pass this condition, and therefore the method will unintentionally return a closed database. When you try and query this closed database, it will therefore throw the illegalstateexception.

Try:

```
public SQLiteDatabase closeDb() {
    mDbHelper.close()
    mDbHelper = null;
}
```

I hope I have helped.

Comment: I don't think so... openDb() performs that check to ensure no NullPointers are thrown, it still returns a valid open database using .getWritableDatabase().

Comment: Would you be able to test this implementation in your coding?

Comment: I just did, it didn't solve the problem... that's how I came up with the theory in my comment.

Comment: Oh, sweet. I'll keep looking into it :)